# Opening above 1MLN connections stucks at 469K

Tags: linux, networking, java, websocket

I need to configure server to handle more than one million opened websocket connections(Ideally 1.5-2.0).

I used configuration from [this](https://mrotaru.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/scaling-to-12-million-concurrent-connections-how-migratorydata-did-it/) blogpost:

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=12000500
sysctl -w fs.nr_open=20000500
ulimit -n 20000500
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mem='10000000 10000000 10000000'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='1024 4096 16384'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='1024 4096 16384'
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=16384
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=16384
```

However, my application stops apply new connections after it reaches 469219 connections. What else can I miss? I really think that something is missing in OS configuration. Our main app written in Java(with Tomcat server) but I also got pretty same results with NodeJS server.

We use Ubuntu with 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you quite explicitly states, that 12M sockets use 46GB RAM for the TCP stack - in addition to whatever else is running.

If you only have 16GB, then start Tomcat with an application, you end up with simply not enough RAM to accept more connections. The NodeJS figures are similar but not equal, because free RAM is similar but not equal.

Upgrade to 128 or 256GB and I suspect it will work fine.

Comment: Actually java application takes about 9GB of  memory, while whole operating system running with this app takes about 11.9GB. There is still about 2,5GB available.

Speaking about NodeJS things are even better. It takes below 3GB.